# Kotlin not able to convert gradle's Action class to a lambda

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

So, while this is quite a kotlin-dsl for gradle specific issue, I think it overall applies to the kotlin language itself, so I am not going to use that tag.

In the gradle API, the class `Action<T>` is defined as:

```
@HasImplicitReceiver
public interface Action<T> {
    /**
     * Performs this action against the given object.
     *
     * @param t The object to perform the action on.
     */
    void execute(T t);
 }
```

So ideally, this should work in kotlin (because it is a class with a SAM):

```
val x : Action<String> = {
    println(">> ${it.trim(0)}")
    Unit
}
```

But I get the following two errors:

```
Unresolved reference it
Expected Action<String> but found () -> Unit
```

Fwiw, even `Action<String> = { input: String -> ... }` doesn't work.

Now here's the really intriguing part. If I do the following in IntelliJ (which btw, works):

```
object : Action<String> {
    override fun execute(t: String?) {
        ...
    }
}
```

IntelliJ pops the suggestion `Convert to lambda`, which when I do, I get:

```
val x = Action<String> {
}
```

which is better, but `it` is still unresolved. Specifying it now:

```
val x = Action<String> { input -> ... }
```

gives the following errors `Could not infer type for input` and `Expected no parameters`. Can someone help me with what is going on?

Comment: All of that works fine for me. Maybe an old Kotlin plugin version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `Action` class in gradle is annotated with [`HasImplicitReceiver`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/HasImplicitReceiver.html). From the documentation:

> Marks a SAM interface as a target for lambda expressions / closures where the **single parameter is passed as the implicit receiver** of the invocation (**`this` in Kotlin**, `delegate` in Groovy) as if the lambda expression was an **extension method** of the parameter type.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So, the following compiles just fine:

```
val x = Action<String> {
    println(">> ${this.trim()}")
}
```

You could even just write `${trim()}` and omit the `this` in front of it.

Answer (score -1):

You need reference the function with class name, like:

```
val x: Action<String> = Action { println(it) }
```

Comment: So this is really weird, but somehow the `Action { println(this) }` seems to work. I have no idea why the lambda is being treated as one with a receiever than a single parameter, but that seems to be the answer at least in the context of a gradle build. But I don't expect the compiler to behave differently for gradle scripts?