# Why configurations.all { conf: Configuration -> ... } compile error with: Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin-dsl

I use build.gradle.kts to build my android project. The following code does NOT compile:

```
configurations.all { conf: Configuration ->
    println(conf)
}
```

error is:

> println(conf) 
>   ^ Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected

But if you remove the `conf:Configuration ->` declaration, it compiled:

```
configurations.all {
    println(conf)
}
```

I know that the first one matches `Iteralbe.all` which need a boolean return value, while the second matches `DomainObjectCollection.all`. But why?

Thanks if any answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer here: [Kotlin not able to convert gradle's Action class to a lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908148/kotlin-not-able-to-convert-gradles-action-class-to-a-lambda).

here: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-and-why-is-the-annotation-hasimplicitreceiver-from-the-gradle-api-working/11231

and the official doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html?_ga=2.154315515.2101643340.1565659650-1852326073.1562576288#sam-with-receiver-compiler-plugin